# Converting Kafka Streams to Parent-Child POJO objects in Java

Tags: apache-kafka

I am working on a POC with the following goals:

a. Write data from Oracle DB tables into topics (say: PARENT, CHILD) using Kafka Connect JDBC Source connector. [ACHIEVED]

b. Convert these topics into Kafka Streams (PARENT_TOPIC -> PARENT_STREAM and CHILD_TOPIC -> CHILD_STREAM) [ACHIEVED]

c. Iterate over the the PARENT_STREAM and get corresponding CHILD records from CHILD_STREAM based on join columns

d. Convert each PARENT record and corresponding CHILD record(s) and create a POJO (Parent has List).

e. Use the above POJO to create JSON objects for further processing.

Currently, I am stuck trying to achieve point (c) onwards - all examples/demos seem to be working on simple transformations (finding count). Stream Joins/Windows does not seem to be meeting my requirements.

Please suggest ways to achieve the above goal. Also, it is the right approach to achieve the end-goal?

Comment: Update: I was able to use inner join between PARENT_STREAM and CHILD_STREAM and create the hierarchy I needed.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below with a code sample rather than just a comment